# Preventing SFTP access to Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an Amazon EC2 instance, and I need to prevent access for a user. Right now the team (we're amateurs) shares a PEM key that is used to access the server through SFTP. I'm looking through AWS and I don't actually see a way to set up some kind of restricted access. Am I just supposed to make a PEM for each user, and if so, how do I configure that and invalidate the old one?

Answer (score 5):

> I have an Amazon EC2 instance, and I need to prevent access for a
>   user.

OK, well for the purposes of this question, it does not matter that it's an EC2 instance. It's a linux server.

> Right now the team (we're amateurs) shares a PEM key that is used to
>   access the server through SFTP.

Oh, HELL no. :)

Seriously, though. There is absolutely *no* reason you should be using shared credentials. Ever. *Especially* if you're novices. Have each team member generate **their own** ssh keypair and then deploy their public key to the server.

> Am I just supposed to make a PEM for each user, and if so, how do I
>   configure that and invalidate the old one?

Yep, exactly. Once you have per-user keypairs created and public keys deployed, just remove the public key that you no longer want to have access.

Comment: That's great, but how do I do it? All this is greek. I googled around and saw something about stopping and unmounting the instance? That seems wrong...

Comment: Again, forget that this is on EC2 for the moment. That doesn't matter. Research ssh key authentication. There are hundreds of guides around, and they're applicable to any Linux server. If you're not comfortable doing this, then consider hiring someone for a couple of hours to get you set off on the right foot.

Comment: I mean, if I could figure it out off of a quick google search, I wouldn't be here. Can you be a bit more specific? I have next to no experience with this sort of thing.

Comment: Ok, here's the thing. You're managing a server, which you know nothing about. That's a bad situation by all accounts. Hire someone to help you out (me even). By doing that, you'll be sure to get things set up in a sustainable way going forward. Don't take this the wrong way, please, but if you can't sort out how to set up key authentication, you should not be managing this server. Someone else should.

Answer (score 1):

The 'PEM' you're using is the Amazon EC2 instance key-pair. You assign that at time you create the instance so that you can login to it to administer the box. There's a script that runs on boot that pulls down the public key and installs it on the server (usually as the ec2-user). You shouldn't be sharing that with anyone who doesn't expressly need to access that server as an administrator. It should be help safe as it's the ultimate access to your server.

I'd suggest you create a new 'sftpuser' user account and then for each of your users add their public key to the authorised keys file. I don't have enough karma to include a link for you. If you google "sshd passwordless login authorised keys" you should fine step-by-step instructions, this is not amazon specific it's general Linux admin. You would then ask everyone to login as the 'sftpuser' and with their generated private key file.

You could alternatively create a user account per team member and add them all to a central group, but, I'd need to understand what you're doing on the server to answer the question more fully.

I'd also suggest that now everyone has access to that original pem file, you should remove it from the server manually and replace it with a new one.